# How to implement SSE with flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask, flask-sse

I tried SSE with flask, without flask-SSE.
The code of server side is following.

```py
# run.py
from sse_test import app
app.run(debug=True, port=5002)
```

```py
# sse_test/__init__.py
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

import sse_test.views
```

```py
# sse_test/views.py
from sse_test import app

from flask import Response
import time

@app.route('/stream')
def stream():
    def sse_response():
        while True:
            yield str(time.time()) + '\n'
            time.sleep(2)
            print('streamed')
    res =  Response(sse_response(), mimetype='text/event-stream')
    return res
```

And, the code of client side is following.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ja">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>SSE Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```js
window.onload = function () {
  const eventSource = new EventSource("http://localhost:5002/stream");

  eventSource.onopen = function (e) {
    console.log('opend');
  }

  eventSource.onmessage = function (e) {
    console.log(e.data);
  }

  eventSource.onerror = function (e) {
    console.log('errored');
  }
}
```

I got 'opened' in browser's console, and got 'streamd' in server's console, but couldn't get response message in browser's console.
Howerver I directly browsed 'http://localhost:5002' with Chrome, Chrome showed response message in the page.

Where is wrong in my code?

Thank you.

Comment: have you read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events), specifically the part that shows you the *format* of events sent from the server? you need `event:` line (not required though) ... but you really need `data:` line(s) and empty lines to signal end of an event

Comment: Also, an SSE connection should be *persistent* - I don't know flask well enough to tell if your code would create a persistent connection, or what it does to be fair